# Creacion de carpetas en Java

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

soy nuevo en esto de programar pero tengo un pequeño codigo en netbeans que le permite al usuario crear una carpeta, el codigo es el siguiente:

```
    package folder;

import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class FOLDER 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String nombre;
        nombre=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nombre de la carpeta a crear");
        File folder = new File("C:\\Users\\PCJAVA\\Desktop\\BATCH\\"+nombre);
        if(!folder.exists())
        {
            folder.mkdir();
            String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Carpeta creada con exito"+nl+"Haga clic para salir","CARPETA",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);                  
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR: Carpeta ya existe","CARPETA",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    } 
}
```

Pero ahora quiero cambiar la ruta estatica por una dinamica y que el usuario pueda elegir en donde crear la carpeta pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo no se si aqui puedan brindarme alguna opcion, gracias de antemano

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]. Te sugiero que modifiques tu pregunta: el IDE Netbeans en este caso no tiene nada que ver con el lenguaje de programación que estás utilizando, que es **Java**. Por lo tanto, tu código está escrito en Java, no en Netbeans.

Comment: Gracias ya hice la modificacion, espero asi sea mas facil encontrar una solucion, te agradezco el comentaio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es probable que necesites JFileChooser: Como en este ejemplo.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class DemoJFileChooser extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JFileChooser chooser;
    public String fileID;
    public JTextField txtField; // Assume this is the text box you placed beside browse button
    public JButton btnBrowse;

    public DemoJFileChooser() {
        btnBrowse = new JButton("Do it");
        btnBrowse.addActionListener(this);
        add(btnBrowse);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        {
            if (e.getSource() == btnBrowse) {
                chooser = new JFileChooser("\\"); // Directory as default
                chooser.setDialogTitle("Select Location");
                chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
                chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

                if (chooser.showSaveDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    fileID = chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
                    txtField.setText(fileID);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

    public static void main(String s[]) { 
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
        DemoJFileChooser panel = new DemoJFileChooser();
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, "Center");
        frame.setSize(panel.getPreferredSize());
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias amigo si me ayudo bastante tu consejo